# Can anyone identify these parts? Technic, liftarm connected to a circle

Tags: part-identification, technic

[image: I'm trying to follow a video MOC tutorial but I can't figure out what this brick is. Part number would help.]

I'm trying to follow a video MOC tutorial but I can't figure out what this brick is. Part number would help.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like some **44224** [Technic, Rotation Joint Disk with Pin Hole and 3L Liftarm Thick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44224) and some **44225** [Technic, Rotation Joint Disk with Pin and 3L Liftarm Thick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44225) - probably two of each, connected by pins.